# importing a CSV file into R Studio installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04

I have recently changed from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. I have installed R Studio again, loaded all the packages and attempted to run code that was working perfectly for over a year under windows/R Studio. Everything works fine with the R code, except the second line of code below (first line is only to show source):

```
UURL <- paste(URL[[nhl]][1],TodayDate,".csv",sep="")
ResultsData <- read.csv(file=UURL)
```

It generates the following error:

> "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

What I know so far is:

- The code previously worked for a year under Windows/R Studio.
- There is no problem with other aspects of the program which are
  accessing the internet via commands like `GetURL`.
- The value of `UURL` is "http://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin15112016.csv" and I have checked the URL and downloaded the csv itself via a browser so there is no problem there.
- The R & R Studio are the latest versions as are all the packages I have installed , including `RCurl`.
- The problem is replicated in two other similar lines of code so there
  is no syntax or line specific error.
- I have read various online posts but none appear to tackle this specific
  question. One suggested using download.file but this does not work either.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW I used 'library' not 'require' so the package loaded OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, using `libcurl` worked on Ubuntu Xenial:

```
df <- read.csv(url("http://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin15112016.csv", method = "libcurl"))
```

Perhaps more simply, `readr::read_csv()` works out of the box:

```
df <- readr::read_csv("http://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin15112016.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but still no go. The first solution does not work as when I attempt to install the libcurl package I get a response most R users are used to seeing. " package ‘libcurl’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)". The second solution requires the 'readr'.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but still no go. The first solution does not work as when I attempt to install the libcurl package I get a response most R users are used to seeing. " package ‘libcurl’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)". The second solution requires the 'readr'. The second solution requires installing 'readr' and this fails with the message "2016-11-15 19:44:07 (523 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpLj85Mz/downloaded_packages/readr_1.0.0.tar.gz’ saved [196055/196055]
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/ajs/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ for modifying ..... etc

Comment: @LostAtSea Do you have `curl` installed? Open a terminal and try `sudo apt install curl`

Comment: Problem solved. Much thanks, the second solution was perfect once I fixed the readr problem I had.